# After I deleted a file, why os.path.abspath() still shows its path?

Tags: python, file, path

```
print(os.path.exists("77.txt"))
print(os.path.isfile("77.txt"))
os.path.abspath("77.txt") 


----------
False
False
'/home/nbuser/library/parent_dir/files_exercises/77.txt'
```

I deleted a file, why the abspath still shows that it exists??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.abspath()` doesn't care whether or not a path *exists*. `abspath()` only manipulates *strings*.

If the input path is not absolute, the current working directory (`os.getcwd()`, a string), is combined with the input path to form a new, valid path string. *That's all this does*.

From the [`os.path.abspath()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname `path`. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

So this joins `os.getcwd()` (which returns a string path) with the input value `path`, using `os.path.join()`. The latter does not make any filesystem checks:

> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of `path` and any members of `*paths` with exactly one directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

So if `path` is an absolute path to begin with, the `os.getcwd()` result is ignored. Otherwise, at most one `os.sep` string is inserted between the two strings. The result is then passed to [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references so that `A//B`, `A/B/`, `A/./B` and `A/foo/../B` all become `A/B`. This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links. On Windows, it converts forward slashes to backward slashes.

This again is just string manipulation. If your input started with `../` then that'd have resulting in an element from the `os.getcwd()` result being removed, etc.